# No returns on Genesis Mining contract

Tags: mining-profitability, monero

I bought a 200H/s mining contract at [genesis mining](https://www.genesis-mining.com/). I allocated 100% of my hash power to Monero. It's been days and I have yet to see any return on my investment yet. The graph is just flat and it looks like it's doing nothing.

I signed up last weds,and it's saturday now. Is it too soon to see any activity on this contract? Or do I just not have enough hash power for it to have any effect?

Comment: A mining calculator suggests you can expect gross revenue of about USD 2.50 per week, before expenses.  Do they subtract your contract fee from your revenues? Is there a minimum amount that must be earned before you see a credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on payouts tab and you will see the payouts there. Disregard the graph on dashboard. The graph will populate once you reach payout threshold of .4 xmr...